# Dividing one audio signal by another one

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

### Short version

I need to *divide* an audio signal by another one (amplitude-wise). How could I accomplish this in the Web Audio API, without using [ScriptProcessorNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScriptProcessorNode)? (with ScriptProcessorNode the task is trivial, but it is *completely unusable* for production due to the inherent performance issues)

### Long version

Consider two audio sources, two [OscillatorNodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OscillatorNode) for example, `oscA` and `oscB`:

```
var oscA = audioCtx.createOscillator();
var oscB = audioCtx.createOscillator();
```

Now, consider that these oscillators are LFOs, both with low (i.e. <20Hz) frequencies, and that their signals are used to *control* a single destination [AudioParam](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioParam), for example, the *gain* of a [GainNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GainNode). Through various routing setups, we can define mathematical operations between these two signals.

**Addition**

If `oscA` and `oscB` are both *directly* connected to the destination AudioParam, their outputs are *added* together:

```
var dest = audioCtx.createGain();

oscA.connect(dest.gain);
oscB.connect(dest.gain);
```

**Subtraction**

If the output of `oscB` is first routed through *another* GainNode with a gain of `-1`, which is then connected to the destination AudioParam, then the output of `oscB` is effectively *subtracted* from that of `oscA`, because we are effectively doing an `oscA + -oscB` op. Using this trick we can subtract one signal from another one:

```
var dest = audioCtx.createGain();
var inverter = audioCtx.createGain();

oscA.connect(dest.gain);

oscB.connect(inverter);
inverter.gain = -1;
inverter.connect(dest.gain);
```

**Multiplication**

Similarly, if the output of `oscA` is connected to *another* GainNode, and the output of `oscB` is connected to the *gain* AudioParam of *that* GainNode, then `oscB` is multiplying the signal of `oscA`:

```
var dest = audioCtx.createGain();
var multiplier = audioCtx.createGain();

oscA.connect(multiplier);
oscB.connect(multiplier.gain);

multiplier.connect(dest.gain);
```

**Division (?)**

Now, I want the output of `oscB` to ***divide*** the output of `oscA`. **How do I do this, *without using ScriptProcessorNode*?**

---

**Edit**

My earlier, *absolutely ridiculous* attempts at solving this problem were:

- Using a PannerNode to control the `positionZ` param, which *did* yield a result that decreased as signal B (`oscB`) increased, but it was completely off (e.g. it yielded `12/1 = 8.5` and `12/2 = 4.2`) -- now this value can be compensated for by using a GainNode with its gain set to `12 / 8.48528099060058593750` (approximation), but it only supports values `>=1`
- Using an AnalyserNode to rapidly sample the audio signal and then use that value (LOL)

**Edit 2**

The reason why the ScriptProcessorNode is essentially useless for applications more complex than a tech demo is that:

1. it executes audio processing on the main thread (!), and heavy UI work will introduce audio glitches
2. a single, dead simple ScriptProcessorNode will take 5% CPU power on a modern device, as it performs processing with JavaScript and requires data to be passed between the audio thread (or rendering thread) and the main thread (or UI thread)

Comment: http://www.ti.com.cn/cn/lit/an/snoa641b/snoa641b.pdf  This is a document regarding multiplication / division of ac signals using op amps but I believe it will provide enough information for you to create the code equivalent.  Hope it helps.

Comment: The important thing to note is with Logs, division becomes subtraction, so Log(sig1) - Log(Sig2) is Log(sig1/sig2) and vice versa.  If I'm in error, please someone yell out so I don't steer the OP wrong.  :D

Comment: @ChrisCaviness -- The problem here is that (AFAIK) `Log` would once again require a ScriptProcessorNode. I don't think it's possible to implement in Web Audio API otherwise.

Comment: I've not worked with the web audio api and my ac signal circuit education was 30 years ago so I'm not going to be much help beyond the general stuff I covered above.  Sorry.  If you did use a Log approach, you'd of course have to anti-log the output to get the true result.

Comment: If you multiply a value by 0.5 it is the same as dividing a value by 2. The gain node does both multiply and divide. It divides when gain.value is <1 by 1/gain.value and multiplies when the value is over 1. Maybe if you offset the phase of one of the oscillators by 180 you can get the desired FX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be noted, that `ScriptProcessorNode` is [deprecated](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#the-scriptprocessornode-interface---deprecated).

If you need `A/B`, therefore you need `1/B`, inverted signal. You can use [WaveShaperNode](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#WaveShaperNode) to make the inversion. This node needs an array of corresponding values. Inversion means that -1 becomes -1, -0.5 becomes -2 etc.

In addition, make sure that you are aware of division by zero. You have to handle it. In the following code I just take the next value after zero and double it.

```
function makeInverseCurve( ) {
  var n_samples = 44100,
      curve = new Float32Array(n_samples),
      x;
  for (var i = 0 ; i < n_samples; i++ ) {
    x = i * 2 / n_samples - 1;
    // if x = 0, let reverse value be twice the previous 
    curve[i] = (i * 2 == n_samples) ? n_samples : 1 / x;
  }
  return curve;
};
```

Working [fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/ishukshin/btcqsdug/). If you remove `.connect(distortion)` out of the audio chain, you see a simple sine wave. Visualization code got from [sonoport](https://sonoport.github.io/visualising-waveforms-with-web-audio.html).

Comment: You probably need only 3 points in the curve array since the node uses linear interpolation for intermediate values.

Comment: Thank you, the explanation is clear. So this will effectively allow most arbitrary math operations to be performed with audio signals as operands.

Comment: What I don't quite get, however, is how this would work with values outside the `[-1, 1]` range. To the best of my knowledge, curve values are not extrapolated.

Comment: @JohnWeisz as far, as I know, signal in web-audio can't be more, than 1 in amplitude.

Comment: It most certainly can, I'm using audio signals to forward values from MIDI controllers going through arbitrary math, currently testing an audio signal to control frequencies, and the Web Audio API handles values `0` to `22050` flawlessly (it likely supports the entire float32 range perfectly, although I'm yet to try).

Comment: @JohnWeisz you always can divide signal by 1000 and then divide the result again after distortion `(1/1000 * 1 / ( S / 1000) = 1/S)`

Comment: Or, since we are talking about floating precision, divide by max float32 value. I will try these soon and post back once done.

Comment: Right, it is the `Oscillator` node, that has max range `[-1;1]`. Another node can give another range.